# How do I stop tool properties from saving when I change it?

Tags: properties

Example:

When I add a UV sphere and change it's segments or rings in the properties. Let's say I changed the Segments to 64 and Rings to 32. Next time I create the sphere I get the same amount of Segments and Rings.

How do I stop the properties from saving these values every time? I just want to use Blender default values and change it myself every single time.